# R - httr - Twitter Error 401 using GET providing Authorization Error

Tags: r, twitter, httr

This is the code that provides the error, along with the output from it.
I'm positive my access keys and tokens are correct. I triple checked them.
I'm guessing my query may be wrong somehow?  My guess was defaulting since_id=0 for my first run, but removal of that provides the same error.

```
mentions = GET(final_url, sig)
mentions

Response [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=@lolhauntzer&until=2016-01-20&since_id=0&result_type=recent&lang=en&count=100]
Date: 2016-01-19 05:09
Status: 401
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Size: 64 B
```

Comment: I just pasted your URL into my Chrome and got a `215` `Bad Authentication data` response.

Answer (score -1):

Woops. Brain lapse.  Need to replace the "@" in the URL with "%40".  The "@" works on my other workstation though, which is kind of baffling right now.

Comment: Your other workstation is _encoding_ the `@` symbol, which apparently was not happening in the second case.